# Drupal Core errors and logging

Tags: log-messages

Looking for a way to suppress PHP errors that come from the Drupal core itself. Obviously, if the issue isn't being fixed in the core code base, we generally assume it's okay to ignore it and that it will get fixed in the core before long.

For example, we occasionally see this error in the logs:

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ControllerDoesNotReturnResponseException: The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned null. Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? in () (line 98 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php).

Which comes from a core library and since we are not familiar with that particular bit of the core, we don't have plans to chase it down. Obviously, issues that originate from our own code is something we would want to see but it there a way to get the Drupal error log to ignore errors that we really can't do anything about?

Just trying to unclutter our logs a bit so we can focus on more important issues (or at least ones we have control over).

Comment: This most likely is not coming from core, but from a custom/contrib module incorrectly calling public APIs from core. Core is tested quite well, errors like this would show up on _many_ sites and would be reported.

Comment: I agree with @Hudri. There is no way that a core module is the root cause of that exception.

Comment: This error is very easy to locate. You should be able to find the controller in the stack trace attached to the error message or, if this is not available, by applying common sense where the error has happened and which module might be providing the route.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no trace or any other information in the error logs. The line above is literally everything that is returned in the log. I assumed it was coming from the core since the error only lists one location for the error and that is in the core. If it is coming from a contrib module as you suggest, there is no indication of where it is coming from or what is triggering it. The error report itself lists no operations at all, completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to database logging, and are comfortable with custom code, decorate the `logger.dblog` service, wrapping the original service with your own implementation. Override the `log` method of `Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog`, in which you filter messages before passing them to the wrapped object's `log` method.